# Meteor CollectionFS Collection is Undefined?

Tags: javascript, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

I am trying to use CollectionFS and GridFS to upload some images to my app and serve them back.

I have the following definitions:

ImageStore.js:

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("images", {
  mongoUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test/',
  transformWrite: myTransformWriteFunction,
  transformRead: myTransformReadFunction, 
  maxTries: 1, 
  chunkSize: 1024*1024
});

EventImages = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [imageStore]
});
```

ImageStorePub.js:

```
Meteor.publish("EventImages", function() {
    return EventImages.find();
});
```

ImageUploadHandler.js:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    EventImages.allow({
        'insert': function() {
            // add custom authentication code here
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

After typing all of this I tried wrapping them all in a `if(Meteor.isServer){...}` despite the fact that they're already in my server folder, but my app is still crashing due to error `ReferenceError: EventImages is not defined
    at server/route handlers/ImageUploadHandler.js:2:1`

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in not assigning the variable on both the client and server.